# Slicing a String and returning the spliced strings

Tags: python, string, function, split, slice

having trouble with my function to slice a string (DNA code) in 8 places and return them. I'm new to the rstrip() and split() functions and I think I may need to use them here, but I don't quite understand how.

Here is my code:

```
input2=open('queryfile.txt','r')

def slice_seq(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,query_seq):
    query_seq=input2
        slice_1=query_seq[a:b + 1]
        slice_2=query_seq[c:d + 1]
        slice_3=query_seq[e:f + 1]
        slice_4=query_seq[g:h + 1]
    return slice_1,slice_2,slice_3,slice_4

a=146
b=917
c=2381
d=2737
e=1
f=155
g=917
h=1057
answer=slice_seq(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,input2)
print(answer)
```

the query file looks like this:

```
emb|AJ000012.1| Mycobacterium tuberculosis recA gene (strain Canetti)
CGAAAGGTCAGATCCGGGCCGGTGAGCACGCCGGATCCGGCCAGGCTAGCGGTGTTCAGCAGATCGTCGG
TGATCCGGACCAGCCGCGCACGCAAGTCGGGCCGCACCGCCGCCAGGGCGTTCGACGCGCCGACGAGCGC
GGACGCGATGTTGCCACACGCGGCGTGTCACACTTGAATCGAACAGGTGTTCGGCTACTGTGGTGATCAT
TCGGAGCAGCCGACTTGTCAGTGGCTGTCTCTAGTGTCACGGCCAACCGACCGATACCGGTCAATCGAAC
ACCGACCACAGGAGAGGCACCATGACGCAGACCCCCGATCGGGAAAAGGCGCTCGAGCTGGCAGTGGCCC
AGATCGAGAAGAGTTACGGCAAAGGTTCGGTGATGCGCCTCGGCGACGAGGCGCGTCAGCCGATTTCGGT
CATTCCGACCGGATCCATCGCACTCGACGTGGCCCTGGGCATTGGCGGCCTGCCGCGTGGCCGGGTGATA
GAGATATACGGCCCGGAATCTTCGGGTAAGACCACCGTGGCGCTGCACGCGGTGGCCAACGCTCAGGCCG
CCGGTGGTGTTGCGGCGTTCATCGACGCCGAGCACGCGCTGGATCCGGACTATGCCAAGAAGCTCGGTGT
CGACACCGATTCGCTGCTGGTCAGCCAGCCGGACACCGGGGAACAGGCACTCGAGATCGCCGACATGCTG
ATCCGCTCGGGTGCGCTTGACATCGTGGTGATCGACTCGGTGGCGGCGCTGGTGCCGCGCGCGGAGCTCG
AAGGCGAGATGGGCGACAGCCACGTCGGGCTGCAGGCCCGGCTGATGAGCCAGGCGCTGCGGAAAATGAC
CGGCGCGCTGAATAATTCGGGCACCACGGCGATCTTCATCAACCAGCTCCGCGACAAGATCGGAGTGATG
TTCGGGTCGCCCGAGACGACAACGGGCGGAAAGGCGTTGAAGTTCTACGCGTCGGTGCGCATGGACGTGC
GGCGGGTCGAGACGCTCAAGGACGGTACCAACGCGGTCGGCAACCGCACCCGGGTCAAGGTCGTCAAGAA
CAAGTGCCTCGCAGAGGGCACTCGGATCTTCGATCCGGTCACCGGTACAACGCATCGCATCGAGGATGTT
GTCGATGGGCGCAAGCCTATTCATGTCGTGGCTGCCGCCAAGGACGGAACGCTGCATGCGCGGCCCGTGG
TGTCCTGGTTCGACCAGGGAACGCAGGATGTGATCGGGTTGCGGATCGCCGGTGGCGCCATCGTGTGGGC
GACACCCGATCACAAGGTGCTGACAGAGTACGGCTGGCGTGCCGCCGGGGAACTCCGCAAGGGAGACCGG
GTGGCGCAACCGCGACGCTTCGACGGATTCGGTGACAGTGCGCCGATTCCGGCGGATCATGCCCGGCTGC
TTGGCTACCTGATCGGAGATGGCAGGGATGGTTGGGTGGGGGGCAAGACTCCGATCAACTTCATCAATGT
TCAGCGGGCGCTCATTGACGACGTGACGCGAATCGCTGCGACGCTCGGTTGTGCGGCCCATCCGCAGGGG
CGTATCTCACTCGCGATCGCTCATCGACCCGGTGAGCGCAACGGGGTACTGGACCTTTGTCGGCGGGCCG
GTGTGCACGGCAAGCTCGCGTGGGAGAAGACGATTCCGAATTGGTTCTTCGAGCCGGACATCGCGGCCGA
CATTGTCGGCAATCTGCTCTTCGGCCTGTTCGAAAGCGACGGGTGGGTGAGCCGGGAACAGACCGGGGCA
CTTCGGGTCGGTTACACGACGACCTCTGAACAACTCGCGCATCAGATTCATTGGCTGCTGCTGCGGTTCG
GTGTCGGGAGCACCGTTCGAGATTACGATCCGACCCAGAAGCGGCCGAGCATCGTCAACGGTCGACGGAT
CCAGAGCAAACGTCAAGTGTTCGAGGTCCGGATCTCGGGTATGGATAACGTCACGGCATTCGCGGAGTCA
GTTCCCATGTGGGGGCCGCGCGGTGCCGCGCTTATCCAGGCGATTCCAGAAGCCACGCAGGGGCGGCGTC
GTGGATCGCAAGCGACATATCTGGCTGCAGAGATGACCGATGCCGTGCTGAATTATCTGGACGAGCGCGG
CGTGACCGCGCAGGAGGCCGCGGCCATGATCGGTGTAGCTTCCGGGGACCCCCGCGGTGGAATGAAGCAG
GTCTTAGGTGCCAGCCGCCTTCGTCGGGATCGCGTGCAGGCGCTCGCGGATGCCCTGGATGACAAATTCC
TGCACGACATGCTGGCGGAAGAACTCCGGTATTCGGTGATCCGAGAAGTGCTGCCAACGCGGCGGGCACG
AACGTTCGACCTCGAGGTCGAGGAACTGCACACCCTCGTCGCCGAAGGGGTTGTCGTGCACAACTGTTCG
CCCCCCTTCAAGCAGGCCGAGTTCGACATCCTCTACGGCAAGGGAATCAGCAGGGAGGGCTCGCTGATCG
ACATGGGTGTGGATCAGGGCCTCATCCGCAAGTCGGGTGCCTGGTTCACCTACGAGGGCGAGCAGCTCGG
CCAGGGCAAGGAGAATGCCCGCAACTTCTTGGTGGAGAACGCCGACGTGGCTGACGAGATCGAGAAGAAG
ATCAAGGAAAAGCTTGGCATTGGTGCCGTGGTGACCGATGACCCCTCAAATGACGGTGTCCTGCCCGCCC
CCGTCGACTTCTGAGCGCGAAGAGCAGGCGCGGGCACTGTGCCTGCGCCTGCTCACCGCGCGATCCCGCA
CCCGCGC
```

Any help would be seriously appreciated! I'm pretty sure my problem is how to deal with the query file so that the function can recognise it and slice it?

Comment: It's called slicing not 'splicing'.

Comment: what is input1 in your code?

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing that out Dhruv.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Do you want to skip the header in your file, or do the slice indices take it to account?

Comment: Sorry I should've clarified, I definitely wanted to skip that header. Desired output was just the string of the DNA bases for each slice on a separate line. Input1 was a different file that had the numbers to slice the sequence at but I took that part out, trying to solve this one step at a time, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suppose you're not that keen on slicing the header in that file, so you have to skip it first, one way or the other:

```
with open('queryfile.txt') as input2:
    # Consume the header
    next(input2)  # or input2.readline()
```

The function then has to read the file line by line to a string, stripping newlines as it goes:

```
dna = ''.join(row.strip() for row in query_seq)
```

I'd also suggest changing how you pass the slice indices to the function a bit:

```
def slice_seq(query_seq, *slices):
```

This way your function accepts 0 or more slices as positional arguments, slices being tuples of indices here. Putting it all together you get:

```
def slice_seq(query_seq, *slices):
    # feel free to use rstrip, if strip seems redundant
    dna = ''.join(row.strip() for row in query_seq)
    return [dna[a:b + 1] for a, b in slices]

a=146
b=917
c=2381
d=2737
e=1
f=155
g=917
h=1057

with open('queryfile.txt') as input2:
    next(input2)
    answer = slice_seq(input2, (a, b), (c, d), (e, f), (g, h))

print(*answer, sep='\n')
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! Was struggling with how to deal with the rows in the query file. What exactly is sep='\n', I assume that's what's putting the new lines in my output? I've never seen it before.

Comment: It is the separator, sep for short, that [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) uses to separate multiple arguments when printing. It defaults to a single space. The asterisk in the function call context [unpacks the list as positional arguments to print](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Answer (score 2):

In the function `slice_seq`, remove the line `query_sec = input2`. That's raising an error. You haven't created a variable named `input2` in the function and no parameter is named so. That is raising an error. You can't set a variable in a function as another variable. You'll have to globalise the other variable first.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unclear from the question whether the result should be 4 slices or 8. Below is an attempt to generalize you code. This code returns 4 slices within a list of lists. The 1st slice is from a->b, 2nd from c->d, 3rd from e->f, and the 4th from g->h.

```
def slice_seq(slice_positions, filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
        slice_out = [data[slice[0]:slice[1]+1] for slice in slice_positions]
    return slice_out

slice_positions = [(146, 917), (2381, 2737), (1, 155), (917, 1057)]
filename = 'queryfile.txt'
slice_out = slice_seq(slice_positions, filename)
print(slice_out)
```

The slice from a->b is:

```
slice_out[0]
```

The slice from c-d is:

```
slice_out[1]
```

as so on.

Comment: I'd use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `slice_out = [data[slices[0]:slices[1]+1] for slices in slice_len]`. To make it more readable would also rename the argument `slice_len` -> `slices` and use `slice_out = [data[slice[0]:slice[1]+1] for slice in slices]`.

Comment: Thanks @martineau I've edited to follow your suggestions